# How to seperate a list of map of strings according to a key value in the list map?

Tags: java, list, maplist

I have a list of Map of Strings like this

```
List<Map<String, String>> dataListMap = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("Charged fare", "3");
        put("Trip ID", "1");
        put("Account", "220");
    }
};
dataListMap.add(dataMap);
dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("Charged fare", "5");
        put("Trip ID", "2");
        put("Account", "220");
    }
};
dataListMap.add(dataMap);
dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("Charged fare", "7");
        put("Trip ID", "3");
        put("Account", "230");
    }
};
dataListMap.add(dataMap);
dataMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    {
        put("Charged fare", "8");
        put("Trip ID", "4");
        put("Account", "230");
    }
};
dataListMap.add(dataMap);
```

I want to separate this list by the account number and convert this to two list in side a List<List<Map<String,String>>> Is there an easy way to do that?Please help

Comment: So you basically want to group the maps by account number? Why not create a POJO to represent the info? How are you getting the data in the first place?

Comment: `dataListMap.stream().collect(groupingBy(m -> m.get("Account"))).values()`

Comment: Just my 2c - I cannot think of a situation where a `List<List<Map<String,String>>>` is a “good” solution.  Keeping yourself to using only pre-defined types like `String` is not good-practice - MUCH better would be to create new classes to model your data.

Comment: thank you very much , the above done the work for me, but i have a doubt, is it possible to convert Collection back to List of Map of Strings?

Comment: Collection<List<Map<String, String>>> accountString = dataListMap.stream().collect(groupingBy(m -> m.get("Account"))).values();
        for(List<Map<String, String>> account: accountString){
           calculateDailyCap(account);
        } is it possible to convert this back to only one list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<List<Map<String, String>>> groupedByIds =
        new ArrayList<>(dataListMap.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i.get("Account")))
                .values());
System.out.println(groupedByIds);
```

I believe that this is what you asked for but you should try specifying your use case, it can probably be better designed.

> Collection<List<Map<String, String>>> accountString = dataListMap.stream().collect(groupingBy(m -> m.get("Account"))).values(); for(List<Map<String, String>> account: accountString){ calculateDailyCap(account); } is it possible to convert this back to only one list?

```
List<Map<String,String>> regroupedList = groupedByIds.stream()
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(regroupedList);
```

Yes you can do it with flatmap, but you already have the list at the start why would you do that?

Stream never affects the result of your initial Collection, it always returns  new result, so it is safe to reuse the list you had at the start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to iterate over the list and push the Maps in two new Lists of Maps according to their Account number.

However without knowing the precise task you're trying to achieve, I would consider creating a new class that holds the three attributes you currently contain in your map.
That would result it way more robust code, that is also easier to extend in the future.